# Query string builder for LIKE operator

Tags: c++, mfc, format

I have tried searching for query to return usernames which are stored in the database. However, I am unable to get the answer for it so far. So here, I am seeking your help.

I have a MFC dialog in which I have an edit control to enter the username and a search button which queries the database for data. I have to retrieve only those usernames, that matchs the string in dit control.

Let's say, there are two records with user names `Sagar` and `Sachin`. So if I enter just `"s"` in the username edit control, the search button event should retrieve both the data for `Sagar` as well as `sachin`.

Fortunately, I have the query which runs well in the access database but do not how to build and format the query in MFC application. The query, which I can run in access database is:

```
select * from USERINFO where Username LIKE [a-z]&"*"
```

Please help me to build and format the query in MFC dialog application on clicking the search button.

Here is the code:

```
list<CUserProperties> CUserOperations::SearchUserDetails(CString sUserName, CString sLastName)
{
    list<CUserProperties> listUserProps;

    m_sFunctionName = L"SearchUserDetails";

    try
    {
        if (sUserName.Trim().IsEmpty() && sLastName.Trim().IsEmpty())
        {
            m_sQuery.Format(_T("SELECT USER_ID, USERNAME, ROLE, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, PASSWORD, CONFIRMPASSWORD FROM USERINFO"));
        }
        else if (sUserName.Trim().IsEmpty() && (!(sLastName.Trim().IsEmpty())))
        {
            m_sQuery.Format(_T("SELECT USER_ID, USERNAME, ROLE, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, PASSWORD, CONFIRMPASSWORD FROM USERINFO WHERE LASTNAME = '%s'"), sLastName);
        }
        else if (sLastName.Trim().IsEmpty() && (!(sUserName.Trim().IsEmpty())))
        {
            m_sQuery.Format(_T("SELECT USER_ID, USERNAME, ROLE, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, PASSWORD, CONFIRMPASSWORD FROM USERINFO WHERE USERNAME = '%s'"), sUserName);
        }
        else
        {
            m_sQuery.Format(_T("SELECT USER_ID, USERNAME, ROLE, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, PASSWORD, CONFIRMPASSWORD FROM USERINFO WHERE USERNAME = '%s' AND LASTNAME = '%s'"), sUserName, sLastName);
        }

        listUserProps = m_dbOperations.SelectUserDataFromDB(m_sFunctionName, m_sQuery);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(m_sFunctionName + L": Exception occured");
    }

    return listUserProps;
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you wrote and that doesn't work.

Comment: For your example with `s` entered in the username field, the query should be `select * from USERINFO where Username LIKE 's%'`, shouldn't it? It's standard SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added the function through which, I am formatting the query and once formatted and built, I pass it to the another function, where it executes the query.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you probably need something like this:

```
CString username;

// Your code: obtain typed username into username

CString querystring;
querystring.Format(_T("select * from USERINFO where Username LIKE '%s%%'"), username);

// perform your query using querystring here
```